# A reference already exists for given audio id and reference does not exists

Tags: ionic2

Hi I have been using cordova-native-plugin for playing audio in my apps. I am having list of audios and I have added buttons play and stop for each item in list.

When I click on play I get this error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: A reference does not exist for the
>   specified audio id. ; Zone:  ; Task: null ; Value: A reference
>   does not exist for the specified audio id. undefined

while sometimes I get: A reference already exists. Though my audio does play properly.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve these errors. I dont want these alerts in between which stops my app itself.

```
playAudio(id, source) {
   console.log(id + "   " + source);
   this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(id.toString(), source);    
   this.nativeAudio.play(id.toString());
}
```

Is there any problem with preloadSimple method.

Comment: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/issues/121

Comment: I have tried this but this solution isn't working. Please note I am using Ionic 2, angular 2 and typescript

Answer (score 1):

I had the the same issue. To fix this issue i'm preloading the audios when the app starts.

In your `app.component.ts` (Im using ionic 3) after checking if the platform is ready, preload your audios with:

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('pin3', 'assets/audios/pin3Audio.mp3');
```

Comment: this will cause the same error once the app is restarted

Answer (score 1):

`preloadSimple` returns a Promise:

```
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple(id.toString(), source).then(
  () => this.nativeAudio.play(id.toString())
);
```

I hope this was helpful. Regards

Comment: In my case the issue was it was playing audio before it was preloaded, so now it is in then() method, so audio will play after the file is preloaded. Thanks